# SQLServer STArea issue with GEOMETRYCOLLECTION resulting in trillion's m2 area

Tags: sql-server, geography-data-type

I've come across a weird issue with SQL Server's handling of `GEOMETRYCOLLECTION` in a Geography data type  resulting in an area (square meters) in the trillion's of square meters. (checked on 2014, 2016, and 2019). This is not an issue with `STGeomFromText` as the same issue occurs when using `STIntersects()`.

Example

```
Select 'POLYGON' Type,Geography::STGeomFromText('POLYGON ((145.396208 -16.499585999999994, 145.3962249999999 -16.499895000000112, 145.396208 -16.499586, 145.39623500000008 -16.499546999999922, 145.396208 -16.499585999999994))', 4326).STArea() Area
Union all
Select 'GEOMETRYCOLLECTION', Geography::STGeomFromText('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION (POLYGON ((145.396208 -16.499585999999994, 145.3962249999999 -16.499895000000112, 145.396208 -16.499586, 145.39623500000008 -16.499546999999922, 145.396208 -16.499585999999994)))', 4326).STArea()
```

Results in

[image]

Does anyone know if this has been reported as a bug to MS and if there is a plan to fix it?

Comment: Your polygon is invalid so all questions about it's area are null and void, the server is entitled to return any answer it likes up to and including turning into a penguin.

Comment: @IanTurton what version of SQL Server are you using, I've never gotten a penguin. Yes, visually it is a line, but the fact remains that SQL returned this from a STIntersects and GEOMETRYCOLLECTION  is handling it incorrectly. Polygon works as expected. That is a bug in the engine.

Comment: It's not that visually it is a line, it is that it fails an isValid() check - there is a self intersection so you can not calculate it's area.